# 50GB HttpRuntime.Cache Persistence Possible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, httpruntime.cache

We have an ASP.NET 4.0 application that draws from a database a complex data structure that takes over 12 hours to push into an in memory data structure (that is later stored in HttpRuntime.Cache). The size of the data structure is quickly increasing and we can't continue waiting 12+ hours to get it into memory if the application restarts. This is a major issue if you want to change the web.config or any code in the web application that causes a restart - it means a long wait before the application can be used, and hinders development or updating the deployment.

The data structure MUST be in memory to work at a speed that makes the website usable. In memory databases such as memcache or Redis are slow in comparison to HttpRuntime.Cache, and would not work in our situation (in memory db's have to serialize put/get, plus they can't reference each other, they use keys which are lookups - degrading performance, plus with a large amount of keys the performance goes down quickly). Performance is a must here.

What we would like to do is quickly dump the HttpRuntime.Cache to disk before the application ends (on a restart), and be able to load it back immediately when the application starts again (hopefully within minutes instead of 12+ hours or days).

The in-memory structure is around 50GB.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: As long as your machine have enough memory (64GB+ in your case) and decent disks array it should be fine... not sure what else you looking as rearchitecting does not look like an option based on the question.

Comment: What you are asking for somewhat defies logic. Why would you want to be interactive with an entire 50GB data structure? Is the ideal solution to this either a better database structure or a proper reporting approach?

Comment: @Stephen the solution is to make your won simple custom cache and use it. The most easy is to create a new table that is flat and contain all that complex data structure and just updated it when its necessary, I think that you follow the wrong path.

Answer (score 9):

> In memory databases such as memcache or Redis are slow in comparison to HttpRuntime.Cache

Yes, but they are very fast compared to a 12+ hour spin-up. Personally, I think you're taking the wrong approach here in forcing load of a 50 GB structure. Just a suggestion, but we use HttpRuntime.Cache as part of a multi-tier caching strategy:

- local cache is checked etc first
- otherwise redis is used as the next tier of cache (which is faster than the underlying data, persistent, and supports a number of app servers) (then local cache is updated)
- otherwise, the underlying database is hit (and then both redis and local cache are updated)

The point being, at load we don't *require* anything in memory - it is filled as it is needed, and from then on it is fast. We also use pub/sub (again courtesy of redis) to ensure cache invalidation is prompt. The net result: it is fast *enough* when cold, and very fast when warm.

Basically, I would look at anything that *avoids* needing the 50GB data before you can do *anything*.

---

If this data isn't really *cache*, but is your **data**, I would look at serialization on a proper object model. I would suggest protobuf-net (I'm biased as the author) as a strong candidate here - very fast and very small output.