# Where is the data cache stored in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpruntime

I want to be specific here, please read the question before marking it duplicate.

I have a case where I would have hit a webservice to gather user information and perform a search query on all the users, the user count expected here is around half a million, as a result I thought adding the users to `HttpRuntime.Cache` the first time and querying from the cached results would do us good.

But my questions are -

1. What is the physical location of the run time cache?
2. Is adding half a million users to cache going to affect the flow?
3. If yes, What is the better way do this?

Kindly revert for more information.

Comment: It's stored in memory, not disk. Do you know the size in MB how much data that is? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876768/where-does-httpruntime-cache-stores-data

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452993/50gb-httpruntime-cache-persistence-possible

Comment: It should be not more than 100 MB

Comment: It should be fine for 100MB, however if you want this to scale, I'd recommend looking into Redis, see the second link.